# Angular js - Highcharts how to set option setInterval to update chart while data is null?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, setinterval

I'm using HighChart library to draw live chart with data return from serve. I set time reload is 3s, but data from serve return null, my Chart drawn in the blank.
I want if data return is null, my chart will wait for new data to update..
Tks all.

my image app:

[image: my image app]

My file js:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/buy'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.dataChart = response.data.data.amount
        //start config for chart    
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        chart: {
            events: {
                load: function() {
                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function() {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time - value x
                            // y = Math.round(Math.random() * 20); // value y
                            y = $scope.dataChart
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 3000);
                    alert($scope.dataChart)
                }
            }
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '1M'
            }, {
                count: 5,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '5M'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 0
        },

        title: {
            text: ''
        },

        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Fake Data: (Random)',
            data: (function() {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push([
                        time + i * 1000,
                        //gioi han truc Y
                        Math.round(Math.random() * 1270)
                    ]);
                }
                return data;
            }())
        }]
    });
    //end chart
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    //alert('error')
    $scope.myWelcome = "error"
});

Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

Comment: Then check if the data is null or not and depending on that - use addPoint() method or do nothing - what is your actually problem with that?

Comment: tks y, I've seen my problem.